# Can someone pleaase clarify the meaning of the entire code mentioned below?

Tags: tcl

```
$seg addPoint "[expr -0.5 * $l] $r 0"
```

I have to convert above TCL code to python code for meshing, but I am unable to understand the above code.Can someone explain me the eqaution in the code?

Answer (score 2):

The first word `$seg` is likely an object that was created, possibly using Tcl::oo as the object-oriented framework.  This is probably a line segment consisting of two points.

`addPoint` looks like a method to add a point to the segment.

`"[expr -0.5*$l] $r 0"`  is a three-item list used as an argument to the method.  Why is it three items?

`expr` is the Tcl command to do math operations, so `expr -0.5 * $l` is just multiplying -0.5 by the value of `$l`.

A possible Python equivalent would be:

```
seg = Segment()
l = 2.0
r = 1.0
seg.addPoint(-0.5 * l, r, 0)
```

...where creating the Segment class and addPoint() method is up to you.

Comment: Hello Chris Heithoff;  I don't know why is it three items. I will try to convert the below Tcl code to Python code.                                                              set Params(radius) 10
set Params(length) 40

# Make the cylindrical revolved surface
proc makeCylinderDB { r l } {
  set seg [pw::SegmentSpline create]
  $seg addPoint "[expr -0.5 * $l] $r 0"
  $seg addPoint "[expr 0.5 * $l] $r 0"
  set line [pw::Curve create]
  $line addSegment $seg

  set pipe [pw::Surface create]
  $pipe revolve -angle 360 $line {0 0 0} {1 0 0}
  pw::Display update

  return $pipe
}

Comment: Thanks for sharing more code.   Looks like you're using Glyph, which describes itself as the scripting language for Pointwise.   http://www.pointwise.com/glyph2/files/Glyph/cxx/GgGlyph-cxx.html    The addPoint method takes a list of three arguments because it's {x y z}.   I was only thinking in two-dimensions.

Why are you converting this to Python?

Comment: I am doing a master's thesis in the Development of a script for parametrized 3D-meshing around a wind turbine blade using pointwise. I have some basic knowledge of python language, so I would try to write code in python.

Comment: $pipe revolve -angle 360 $line {0 0 0} {1 0 0}   Can you help me also this code?

Comment: It looks like `$pipe` is an object that has a method called `revolve`.    

I found this reference page for Glyph.   http://www.pointwise.com/glyph2/files/Glyph/cxx/GlyphSurface-cxx.html#pw.Surface.revolve which describes that revolve is a method of a surface object.  I've never used Glyph or Pointwise before.    I recommend that you learn Glyph using Tcl.   From what I've read, there are some Python interfaces to pointwise, but they seem to be servers which translate Python commands back to Tcl again.   It's probably well worth your time to learn Tcl instead of writing in Python.